# Rails 3 app with PostgreSQL - Getting the list of messages grouped by converstation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am running a rails 3 app that models email messages. The app is deployed on on Heroku so the backend db is PostgreSQL. Messages threads are simple modeled by the thread_id field in the Posts table. When the user post a new Post, let's call it p1 then p1.thread_id=p1.id. If the user reply to p1 with p2 then p2.thread_id=p1.thread_id.

I need to write a query to select the messages sent to a certain user. The resulting list must contain only one message per thread and that message must be the latest message in the thread. I also need to know how many messages are in each thread.

Using the following select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(thread_id) * FROM "posts"
```

does not work as it does not returns the post sorted by last first.

This one does not work either:

SELECT DISTINCT ON(thread_id) * FROM "posts" ORDER BY thread_id, posts.created_at DESC

as the posts are ordered first by thread_id.

Posts table:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "content"
    t.string   "content_type"
    t.text     "options"
    t.string   "type"
    t.integer  "receiver_id"
    t.integer  "sender_id"
    t.integer  "circle_id"
    t.text     "data_bag"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "thread_id"
    t.datetime "posted_at"
  end
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind getting your hands dirty with a bit of SQL you can use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) to get the job done. You can get the post IDs with this SQL:

```
select id
from (
    select id,
           rank() over (partition by thread_id order by created_at desc)
    from posts
    where receiver_id = #{user.id}
) as dt
where rank = 1
```

If you want more columns add them to both SELECT clauses. The `#{user.id}` is, of course, the recipient that you're interested in.

The interesting part is the window function:

```
rank() over (partition by thread_id order by created_at desc)
```

This will partition the table into groups based on `thread_id` (sort of a localized GROUP BY), order them by the timestamp (most-recent first), and then `rank()` yields 1 for the first entry in each group, 2 for the second, etc.

Given a table that looks like this:

```
=> select * from posts;
 id | receiver_id | thread_id |     created_at      
----+-------------+-----------+---------------------
  1 |           1 |         2 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00
  2 |           1 |         2 | 2011-02-01 00:00:00
  3 |           1 |         2 | 2011-03-01 00:00:00
  4 |           1 |         3 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00
  5 |           1 |         4 | 2011-01-01 00:00:00
  6 |           1 |         3 | 2011-01-01 13:00:00
  7 |           2 |        11 | 2011-06-06 11:23:42
(7 rows)
```

The inner query gives you this:

```
=> select id, rank() over (partition by thread_id order by created_at desc)
   from posts
   where receiver_id = 1;

 id | rank 
----+------
  3 |    1
  2 |    2
  1 |    3
  6 |    1
  4 |    2
  5 |    1
(6 rows)
```

And then we wrap the outer query around that to peel off just the top ranking matches:

```
=> select id
    from (                                                                  
        select id,
               rank() over (partition by thread_id order by created_at desc)
        from posts
        where receiver_id = 1
    ) as dt
    where rank = 1;

 id 
----
  3
  6
  5
(3 rows)
```

So add the extra columns you want and wrap it all up in a [`Post.find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-find_by_sql) and you're done.

Comment: How would I do this query on Postgresql 8.3?

Comment: @Matteo: You have another question sorting out the 8.3 issues, right?  I checked 8.4 for the window functions but neglected to check 8.3, sorry about that.