# PostgreSQL query works locally but not on Heroku (same data)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Here is query:

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "over"
                 select *, rank() over (partition by thread_i...
                                          ^

```
     SELECT *
     FROM (                                                                  
             select *, rank() over (partition by thread_id order by created_at DESC)
             from posts
             where circle_id IN (134) OR (receiver_id=3)
           ) as dt
     WHERE rank = 1
```

EDIT: here is a detailed explanation of what I am trying to do:
[Rails 3 app with PostgreSQL - Getting the list of messages grouped by converstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314991/rails-3-app-with-postgresql-getting-the-list-of-messages-grouped-by-converstati)

It turns out the Heroku shared DB is a PostgreSQL version 8.3 therefore no windows function so the question become how can I do this query in PostgreSql 8.3?

THANKS!

Comment: The derived table solutions from Derek and Yahia should work with 8.3. There is a chance that `posts.created_at = dt.maxdt` could produce multiple results for a single thread though. You might want to include a client-side check to deal with duplicate `thread_id,created_at` pairs. The chance of a duplicate is quite low but "low" and "zero" aren't quite the same.

Comment: updated my answer with a possible solution for the duplicate problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
SELECT p.*
 FROM (                                                                  
         select x.thread_id, max(x.created_at) as maxdt
         from posts x
         where x.circle_id IN (134) OR x.receiver_id=3
         group by x.thread_id
       ) as dt
 INNER JOIN posts p ON p.thread_id = dt.thread_id and p.created_at = dt.maxdt 
 ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
```

EDIT - as per comment:

```
SELECT p.*
 FROM (                                                                  
         select x.thread_id, max(x.created_at) as maxdt, max (OID) maxo
         from posts x
         where x.circle_id IN (134) OR x.receiver_id=3
         group by x.thread_id
       ) as dt
 INNER JOIN posts p ON p.thread_id = dt.thread_id and p.created_at = dt.maxdt AND p.OID = dt.maxo
 ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
```

Comment: There is an exceedingly small chance that you'll get duplicates if Matteo manages to get multiply entries with the same `thread_id,created_at` pair. I'd deal with that possibility in Ruby though.

Comment: see the edit above... it takes care of the possible duplicate problem by only returning the record with the highest OID (assuming it is the most current...) for a given combination of `thread_id` and `created_at`

Comment: Nice, the old `oid` trick. I'd give you another upvote for that but I only have one account :) Shame that the Heroku hasn't updated their shared DBs to 8.4 to get window functions. On the rare chance that there is a match I don't think it matters which one you pick, you just need a way to pick exactly one.

Comment: Guys thank you so much for your help!!! Both of you saved me so much time. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

This should get you there:

```
 SELECT p.*
 FROM (                                                                  
         select thread_id, max(created_at) as maxdt
         from posts
         where circle_id IN (134) OR (receiver_id=3)
       ) as dt
 INNER JOIN posts p ON p.thread_id = dt.thread_id and p.created_at = dt.maxdt
```

Comment: There is an exceedingly small chance that you'll get duplicates if Matteo manages to get multiply entries with the same `thread_id,created_at` pair. I'd deal with that possibility in Ruby though.